# Does android studio have a feature that highlights the method(in structure pane on the left) where my current cursor position is?

Tags: android, android-studio

When I place the cursor on a line, I want the corresponding method highlighted in the "Structure" pane on the left side.  Does Android Studio have such a feature?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is called "Autoscroll from source".  And the structure pane is not necessarily on the left, you can have it anywhere you want.

Answer (score 1):

As @nasch said, just enable "Autoscroll from source" [image]